# Flutter error says 'Error: Can't access 'this' in a field initializer.'?

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is my code:

[image]

[image]

The error is at line :

`onTap: () => _showActionSheet(this.context),`

I don't know whats the problem is with this line as I'm a beginner in the flutter. So please help me solving this error.

Comment: Can you include code-snippet instead of code-snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you may use method instead of variable for this.

```
List<Marker> _list()=>[...]
```

You can do lazy initialization, but sometimes you may face some issue update context.

```dart
late List<Marker> _list = [...]
```